# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/node_modules/dotenv/lib' - create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dotenv

I am trying to store an API key in a `.env` file. The app I'm building I started with `create react app` and it is now throwing this error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/x/Desktop/prog/x/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 3:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/x/Desktop/prog/x/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 5:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/x/Desktop/prog/x/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

I am very new to using .env to properly manage sensitive data. Here is how my .env file is set up:

```
REACT_APP_key = '1234ABC'
```

And here is how I call it:

```
require('dotenv').config
const request = require('superagent')
const url = 'https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/'

//dictionary
export function getDictionaryDefinition() {
  return request
    .get(`${url}dog`)
    .set('X-Mashape-Key', process.env.REACT_APP_key)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use dotenv in a React application. There is no such thing as "process.env" in the browser.

But if you insist on using it, look into projects [such as this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) which add dotenv support to webpack.